# Different getUser() return with HTTP & HTTPS

Tags: facebook, http, redirect, https, zero

I send you this message because I'm stuck in the establishment of an application that I made for a contest on Facebook.

I have two differents URL for my application, one in HTTPS and one other in HTTP. but when the user comes on one of this url that's doesn't correspond to her security setting, the getUser() method return 0 and i'm redirected to the home of my application and not to the target page with the app_data param i passed in the Facebook URI.

What is the problem ? What to do? Thank you in advance

Sorry for my bad English, I'm French.

Comment: Seems to be not validating the user.. Are you connecting correctly over SSL?

Comment: Yes, i'm connecting correctly, the code of my bootstrap is the following : http://vpaste.net/NjZfK

Comment: The "full" code here: http://vpaste.net/GOVXF

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, not only me and you who gad it, many developers suffered from same issue. I spent four days to solve it, and I tried tons of solutions without any result.
Finally I solved it and got the problem:
I you are sure about the configurations and other things ...
then Solution is to host your application on web hosting server with real domain. then configure your application to use this domain ...

I do advice you to try this solution.